Удаление переменной из памяти Python
У меня технический вопрос. Пишу на Python. Две переменные задаются таким образом:
a = 5
b = a
del a
print(b)

Программа выводит:
5

Почему программа выводит 5, а не None?
Ведь две переменные указывают на одну область памяти и мы ее удаляем, получается переменная b должна быть None. Почему она все-равно равняется 5? Очищается ли эта область памяти при вызове del или она переписывается в другое место, но как тогда ее очистить?

С чего вы решили, что они указывают на одну "область памяти"? Почему вы думаете, что присваивание работает как передача ссылки, а не копирование значения?

a указывала на 5 и b указывала на 5. Вы удалили a, но 5 удалять нельзя, так как она достижима из b. Непосредственно удаляется только имя a, всё остальное удаляет сборщик мусора, но для него работы в вашем примере не оказалось. (Не говоря о том, что 5 - небольшое целое из специального списка в Питоне, элементы которого не удаляются никогда).

@SwaD Это ж Python, тут все сущности - "объекты первого класса" )

связанные вопросы: 1. Присваивание целых (int) в Питоне, 2. Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?

Если мне память не изменяет:
Когда мы инициализируем переменную a = 5 то в памяти создаётся объект типа int со значением 5, и переменная a начинает ссылаться на этот объект (хотя если в памяти уже был объект int=5 то в целях экономии памяти новый объект может и не создаться)
Теперь b = a переменная b начинает ссылаться на тот же объект, что и a. И тут важно, что не происходит копирование переменной a, а получается копирование ссылки на объект, которым является число 5. В памяти в этот момент существует один объект — число 5, и обе переменные ссылаются на него (а может и еще другие переменные на него ссылаются, но это уже оптимизации самого Python).
А вот сам del a удаляет непосредственно переменную a, но не объект, на который она ссылается. Поскольку на объект 5 по-прежнему ссылается переменная b, объект не удаляется, и память не очищается.
И теперь самое очевидное print(b) отработает поскольку переменная b всё ещё указывает на объект 5, ведь del a просто удалил переменную a, но не int 5 в памяти.
А вот непосредственно из памяти объекты удаляет сборщик мусора. В Python для удобства и автоматизации/оптимизации этот самый сборщик сам находит для очистки объекты, которые больше не имеют ссылок. В данном случае объект 5 остаётся в памяти до тех пор, пока существует хотя бы одна ссылка на него. А вот когда все ссылки на объект будут удалены (например, если мы также сделаем del b или присвоим ей другое значение), объект станет "доступен для удаления", и сборщик мусора его выгрузит из памяти.
Так что если хотим полностью удалить объект из памяти, то придётся найти и удалить все ссылки на этот объект. В данном случае:
a = 5
b = a
del a
del b  

Теперь нет ссылок на объект 5 и int 5 будет выгружен из памяти сборщиком мусора при следующей его ревизии объектов в памяти.

К слову, небольшие целые числа в диапазоне от -5 до 256 кэшируются интерпретатором и хранятся в специальном массиве, и они никогда не удаляются, поскольку часто используются.
Забавный пример:
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 300
>>> a is 10
True
>>> b is 300
False

Числа вне диапазона -5, 256 интерпретатор тоже будет пытаться оптимизировать, но только если они находятся в одной строке (или одном файле). В командной строке интерпретатора так не работает:
>>> d = 400
>>> d is 400
False

а так будет:
a = 5
b = 300

print(a is 5)  # True
print(b is 300) # True


Так же в Python есть интернирование строк — это своего рода оптимизация, которая позволяет уменьшить количество строковых объектов в памяти по средству кэширования некоторых строк (происходит автоматически для коротких строк).
a = "hello world!"
b = "hello world!"
print(a is b)  # True

a = "hello my litl world is the good job, " * 300
v = "hello my litl world is the good job, " * 300
print(a is v)  # False

z = f"hello {b}" 
x = f"hello {b}" 
print(z is x)  # False

import sys
a = sys.intern(a)
v = sys.intern(v)
print(a is v)  # Теперь True, строки интернированы вручную

z = sys.intern(z)
x = sys.intern(x)
print(z is x)  # Тоже True


В общем, del не удаляет объект, а просто удаляет переменную и её копию ссылки на объект. Надеюсь понятно изложил

Ещё можно вспомнить про интернирование строк. Там тоже забавно всё. )

@CrazyElf  дополнил ответ;) к слову для меня стало откровением, что нужно прям неприлично длинную строку сделать, чтобы питон создал новый строковый объект в памяти, а не воспользовался кешированным..

Там по-моему скорее зависит от того, константная ли строка или вычисляемая. Но в общем детали реализации могут отличаться )

@CrazyElf да, f строки питон самостоятельно не кеширует, дополню в примере

Дополнительная иллюстрация:
import gc

class A():
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Объект класса A'

    def __del__(self):
        print('Объект всё', flush=True)

a = A()
print(a, id(a), flush=True)
b = a
del a
print(b, id(b), flush=True)
del b
gc.collect()

Вывод:
Объект класса A 2108801486752
Объект класса A 2108801486752
Объект всё

От того, что вы удалили переменную a, сам объект, на который она указывала, никуда не делся. Теперь на тот же самый объект указывает другая переменная b. Вот когда на этот объект уже никто не будет указывать, тогда его (когда-нибудь) соберёт GC, как уже написали. Ну либо он удалится, если вы напрямую вызовете gc после удаления всех ссылок на объект.
P.S. Спасибо insolor, дописал про отслеживание собственно удаления.

Ну узнать можно, но только в своем классе, если __del__ переопределить

@insolor О, это хорошее замечание

Вам нужно активизировать сбор мусора после удаления переменной и почистить память после удаления ссылки на область памяти.
import gc

# Manual object cleaning
    
del x
gc.collect()


Если на объект есть ещё ссылки (как в коде в вопросе), то объект не удалится. Кроме того, в вопросе используется заранее инстанциируемый питоном объект для числа 5, который вообще не удаляется.

del x удалит у вас только локальную переменную x. Если переданный объект при этом снаружи будет храниться в какой-то переменной, он не будет удален.

Я старался показать подход, который может удалить данные в случае, если у вас большая таблица или еще что. У меня этот метод используется для очистки памяти после удаления датафреймов. Мне показалось, что суть вопроса в этом.

Суть в том, что del внутри функции не возымеет желаемого действия: сам вызов функции создает локальную переменную x, и del удаляет только эту локальную переменную, но никак не влияет на сам объект или другие ссылки на объект. del нужно применять прямо по месту, и там же делать gc.collect().

Спасибо @insolor. Изменил ответ.
